# What will help transcribe what I hear in my mind to actual notes

Tags: ear-training

Sometimes I hear music in my mind and the more complex it is the harder it is for me to transcribe to singing or to the melody or chords that I hear.

What can help? Is it ear training and if so how can I learn this?

Comment: Music theory also helps a ton in my experience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple glib answer - go to a teacher. But actually, this sort of skill is difficult to achieve on one's own. Having an expert who takes you in the right direction is the best thing. Once you have learned to sing scales, and understand what they're all about, it will be much easier to transcribe. Knowing intervals, through scale knowledge, will be of great use also.

A simple start point would be to play a note or chord on whatever instrument you play, then sing it, then, say, the 6th note in that scale, then play it to check it. There are a few variations to try, but always play straight after as a check. Then listen to simple tunes, and try to write them on the stave.

Rhythm wise, counting is the best way, working from 4 in the bar, tapping/playing simple rhythms, then writing them down. Keep rhythm and melody separate until each is pretty good. Try something like Jingle Bells for writing the rhythm pattern - no need even for a stave!

Comment: yes I guess intervals are a good way especially with melodies or notes that I hear played together - i hope that will help though to know how to put whats only is on my mind in to the actual notes

Answer (score 7):

Practice. When you hear anything (that you like) internally, try to write it down. At first you may only have melodic contours. With a bit of practice, you will be able to put a rhythm to these. Later you can learn to put in exact interval. I find that having a melodic contour and a pretty good idea of the rhythm is sufficient; I'm going to be doing a bunch of editing anyway.

Comment: thanks the problem usually is with difficult melodies the easiest I can write but I guess it is a practice like you said